# open kdiff3 with 2 files selected from different panels

Tags: powershell, far-manager

So, I saw another question that shows how to open multiple files in vim using the line of code

```
ps: & vim @(Get-FarPath -Selected) #
```

But that seems to work only with files selected from the active panel.

If i were to have two panels that I was doing a directory/file compare on, how would I open an instance of kdiff3 when selecting a file on panel-1, and have kdiff3 open the same named file on panel-2, for each of the selected files on panel-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 possible ways to achieve this, one of which I will list, and the other includes PowerShellFar and FarNet.

1. Select the files in panel1 or panel2
2. press `ctrl+g` to pull up the dialog for `execute command on selected`
3. type `"C:\Program Files\kdiff3\kdiff3.exe" "!\!.!" "!#!\!^!.!"`

if you have kdiff3 on your path, you can replace `"C:\Program Files\kdiff3\kdiff3.exe"` in the command with `kdiff3`

If you press `ctrl+g` to open the `execute command on selected` dialog and then press `F1` it leads to the contextual help.  From there you can select `special symbols` topic, and see a list of what the various commands mean such as `!\` and `!.!`